# Disconnect the SAS on T7500

Tags: ssd, raid, sata, dell-precision, sas

I have a Dell Precision T7500.

In BIOS I have turned off the SAS controller, which means that I can't use two HD's and the DVD drive, which I am fine with.

I have an Adata SU800 SSD in it, which I assume is connected to a SATA connector.

Can I somehow disconnect the SAS controller physically? I'm asking as it takes 30 seconds of black screen time before the Dell screen appears when I hit the power switch. I think it might be faster if I unplug the SAS, but can' work out which part it is and am scared of breaking something.

The specsheet is here: http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/dell_precision_t7500_specsheet.pdf

The following screenshot shows what happens when I enable the SAS controller. It takes about 30 seconds to initialize, during which it detects 2 SAS hard drives and 1 DVD drive.

[image: SAS 1]

The following screenshot shows where I turned it off in the BIOS settings:

[image: SAS Bios Setup]

Comment: "Press Ctrl-C to run SAS Configuration Utility" – have you tried that? Maybe you can tell the controller there are no drives so it will skip probing them. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [T7500 manual](http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_dell_precision_workstation/precision-t7500_service%20manual_nl-nl.pdf), page your SAS connectors are directly on the motherboard. They are not from an add in card. It using an on-motherboard LSI 1068e chip.

See [image: T7500 motherboard with SAS ports marked]

So no, there is no way to completely remove the SAS part. At least no without changing the motherboard.

You could connect a drive to a SAS port though. That will  prevent it from timing out while waiting for drives to become available.

I am confused by the "In BIOD I have turned off the SAS controller" part though. Exactly what did you turn off? Because it is most certainly not turned off while you are waiting for it.

For me iot feels as if you went into the BIOS and disabled some 'be able to boot from option' (but still power up and scan all devices... and time out if you do not find any)...  Can you add a screenshot or a precise option off what you changed.

Comment: I've added some screenshots and more details to my question. Thanks for the help!